# Exception: "Cannot Be cast to java.util.ArrayList" when storing ArrayList from intent

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-intent, android-recyclerview

I getting an exception `cannot be cast to java.util.ArrayList` when I try to store an ArrayList that was retrieve from a intent inside a Fragment class.

Right now I am using intent from my adapter to pass an ArrayList to my fragment class. My fragment class will retrieve the data by using Parcelable and store it into an object so I can use the data for my fragment classes. But the issue is once it retrieves the data, it throws an exception. Is it because I'm using the wrong object to store my data?

**MainAdapter class:**

```
final Intent intent = new Intent(view.getContext(), DetailActivityFragment.class);
intent.putExtra("baking_app", mbakingAppsDataModels.get(position));
Log.d("onClick mBDM size: ", mbakingAppsDataModels.get(position)+"");
//intent.putExtras(args);
view.getContext().startActivity(intent);
```

**Fragment class:**

```
Bundle args = getIntent().getExtras();
ArrayList<BakingAppsDataModel> bakingAppsDataModels = args.getParcelable("baking_app");
```

**Exception:**

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                             Process: com.example.kavin.bakingapp, PID: 22716
                                                                             java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.kavin.bakingapp/com.example.kavin.bakingapp.ui.DetailActivityFragment}: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.example.kavin.bakingapp.Data.BakingAppsDataModel cannot be cast to java.util.ArrayList
                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2817)
                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2892)
                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0)
                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1593)
                                                                                 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105)
                                                                                 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6541)
                                                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                 at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240)
                                                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)
                                                                              Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.example.kavin.bakingapp.Data.BakingAppsDataModel cannot be cast to java.util.ArrayList
                                                                                 at com.example.kavin.bakingapp.ui.DetailActivityFragment.onCreate(DetailActivityFragment.java:30)
```

Comment: is this a list ?? `mbakingAppsDataModels` .

Comment: Instead of using backticks you can just indent your code by 4 spaces to format it correctly.

Comment: @SantanuSur its an ArrayList

Comment: @csmckelvey Will do I will keep that i mind

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably you pass an Object of type BakingAppsDataModel in the Intent, since the Method bakingAppsDataModels.get(position) returns an object.

Try to replace this:

```
ArrayList<BakingAppsDataModel> bakingAppsDataModels = args.getParcelable("baking_app");
```

with this:

```
BakingAppsDataModel bakingAppsDataModels = args.getParcelable("baking_app");
```

Comment: so my goal is when a user clicks on a specific food on the main menu, it'll use intent and launch a new screen about all the information about that specific food. Is using get(position) a good approach to make sure its passing the correct data base on the food the user chosen?

Comment: Yes it is a good approach, but obviously you need to assert that no wrong indexes are accessed. Another approach would be to use identifiers in the model, which are mapped to the views in the list. However, I would use your approach since it is less complicated and more efficient.

Answer (score 0):

This is because what you're putting to the bundle is not the List but the item of the list:

```
final Intent intent = new Intent(view.getContext(), DetailActivityFragment.class);

// You are adding the item here instead of the List
intent.putExtra("baking_app", mbakingAppsDataModels.get(position));
```

it should be:

```
final Intent intent = new Intent(view.getContext(), DetailActivityFragment.class);

intent.putExtra("baking_app", mbakingAppsDataModels);
```